# Paypal "Buy now" button - how to know that payment was successful

Tags: java, paypal

I am trying to add "Buy now" button to my Java web application. When generating the button in Paypal, there's option to add URL of success page and cancel page. 
For example, success URL could be `http://www.example.com/success`

But how to check that the payment was successful and the user was redirected from Paypal (not entered the success URL manually)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an option to add a notify_url, via which PayPal will send you an Instant Payment Notification via a POST, or there are other PayPal APIs you can use for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into PayPal's Payment Data Transfer API: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

Looks like this will give you the data you need to ensure a successful transaction before displaying a product link or purchase info.